# Yii2 multiple table in gridview

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have 2 tables with `strategy` and `risk_colors` [image: relations].

I generated Model and CRUD with GII and modified it just a little to get `risk_value` column in my GridView widget.

Here is my `Strategy.php`

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\db\Expression;
/**
 * This is the model class for table "strategy".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $strategy_title
 * @property string $strategy_description
 * @property string $strategy_current_money
 * @property int $risk_colors_id
 *
 * @property SelectedStrategies[] $selectedStrategies
 * @property RiskColors $riskColors
 */
class Strategy extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'strategy';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['strategy_title', 'strategy_description', 'strategy_current_money', 'risk_colors_id'], 'required'],
            [['strategy_current_money', 'risk_colors_id'], 'integer'],
            [['strategy_title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['strategy_description'], 'string', 'max' => 2055],
            [['risk_colors_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => RiskColors::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['risk_colors_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'strategy_title' => 'Strategy Title',
            'strategy_description' => 'Strategy Description',
            'strategy_current_money' => 'Strategy Current Money',
            'risk_colors_id' => 'Risk Color ID',
            'riskValue' => Yii::t('app', 'Risk'),
            'colorNumber' => 'Color Number',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSelectedStrategies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SelectedStrategies::className(), ['strategy_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getRiskColors()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(RiskColors::className(), ['id' => 'risk_colors_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return risk value
     */
    public function getRiskValue()
    {
        return $this->riskColors->risk_value;
    }

    /**
     * @return Get risk value list for dropdown
     */
    public function getRiskValueList()
    {
        $droptions = RiskColors::find()->asArray()->all();
        return ArrayHelper::map($droptions, 'id', 'risk_value'); 
    }

    /**
     * @return Get risk value list for dropdown
     */
    public function getColorNumberList()
    {
        $droptions = RiskColors::find()->asArray()->all();
        return ArrayHelper::map($droptions, 'id', 'color_number'); 
    }

}
```

here is my [index.php](https://hastebin.com/cuyefigaje.xml).

After all i got `risk_value` column in my GridView, but it looks like i cant sort my table by this field. Here is [image: screenshot].

Here is my [Search Model](https://hastebin.com/olezojumim.xml)

**So my question is what should i do to make this field sortable?**

Comment: please give your StrategySerch.php model

Comment: Post your code directly in question.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview

Comment: your `index.php` points to the wrong link, it shows model rather than the view, and you should add the `StrategySearch` model rather than `Strategy` model

Comment: Thank you, i edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `StrategySearch.php`

```
public function search($params)
{
     $query = Strategy::find()->joinWith(['riskColors']);

     // add conditions that should always apply here

     $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
         'query' => $query,
     ]);

     $dataProvider->sort->attributes['risk_colors_id'] = [
         'asc' => ['risk_colors.risk_value' => SORT_ASC],
         'desc' => ['risk_colors.risk_value' => SORT_DESC],
     ];

     $this->load($params);

     if (!$this->validate()) {
         // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
         // $query->where('0=1');
         return $dataProvider;
     }

     // grid filtering conditions
     $query->andFilterWhere([
         'id' => $this->id,
         'strategy_current_money' => $this->strategy_current_money,
         // 'risk_colors_id' => $this->risk_colors_id,
         'risk_colors.risk_value' => $this->risk_colors_id
     ]);

     $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'strategy_title', $this->strategy_title])
           ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'strategy_description', $this->strategy_description]);

     return $dataProvider;
}
```

Refere [GridView Sorting](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview)

Comment: almost. Now 'risk value' is sortable, but i cant use 'find' option. If i type '10' and hit Enter nothing is happen. Here is screenshot https://imgur.com/a/X1azpLS

Comment: @Zurab Gostohov If my answer is correct then mark as tick because it's usefull to another one.

Comment: Have to go right now. I will check you solution soon, but i think it will work.

Comment: I tested your refer and it didnt work. After that i red Refere GridView Sorting and rewrote my Search model. Here is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/gostohov/524f48dbcb5be309f81dde758345800a)

and screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/W2FV5vv As you can see field rendered correctly, but when i try to sort 'risk' field i got this error https://imgur.com/a/DPaNcaf

Comment: I solve my issue. 
I replace this 
''risk_colors_id.risk_value' =>  $this->riskColors,'
to this
'risk_value => $this->Colors'